# module and non-module scripts are not loaded one after the other in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

The project I am working on requires use of two script tags

````
<script type='module' src='external'></script>

<script>
some code that uses variables from script 1 but it is not available
</script>```
````

Comment: The first <script> is not a script at all, it's a module. Variables from it will never be available in the global scope. Your second code needs to be made a module as well, and `import { variables } from 'external'`. By explicitly spelling out this dependency, you will also ensure that they run in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `import variable from 'external'` in the second script and change second script tag to module as well. As you can't access module variable in global scope.

Comment: I have made the variables global from the first script, window[foo] = module object

Comment: Yes you can do it that way but that not a good way according to me. But its good that your issue resolved.